# jQuery recursive find

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="TemplateBindVarsTable" class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="control-label">${MeetingName}</td>
    <td class="form-control" style="border:0"><input id="${MeetingName}" 
     type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="control-label">${MeetingLocation}</td>
    <td class="form-control" style="border:0"><input id="${MeetingLocation}" 
    type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have the following jQuery code that goes against this:

```
function processTemplate() {
    var rows = $('#TemplateBindVarsTable').find("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // NONE OF THESE WORK
        var cells = rows[i].children();
        var key = rows[i].find("td.control-label").text();
        var val = rows[i].find("td.control-label>input").val();
        alert('key: ' + key + ", val: " + val);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?  Shouldn't I be able to get rows back and then run a find/children on them?!

Comment: `rows[i]` is not a jQuery object anymore. Loop through jQuery objects with `.each()` instead of a for loop.

Comment: What's recursive about the example?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to modify it a little like following to convert DOM object to jQuery object on which you can execute jQuery's methods like `.children()` and `.find()`:

```
function processTemplate() {
    var rows = $('#TemplateBindVarsTable').find("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // NONE OF THESE WORK
        var cells = $(rows[i]).children();
        var key = $(rows[i]).find("td.control-label").text();
        var val = $(rows[i]).find("td.control-label>input").val();
        alert('key: ' + key + ", val: " + val);
    }
}
```